# 手えふった - what is the "え” here?

Tags: particles, manga, compensatory-lengthening

Context:

[image]

Why "え" is used here? What does it mean?

Comment: I think it means the same as 手**を**ふった. Not sure if it is dialectal or colloquial.

Comment: FYI, it looks to me like the え is a small ぇ. I find that the use of small vowels is a common way of "transcribing" the speech of people who drag out their vowels.

Comment: @senshin, oh, now I see it too. But in this case no particles are used at all...

Comment: <in this case no particles are used at all> Exactly.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The small `ぇ` in `手ぇふった` is a way of indicating in writing the compensatory lengthening of the vowel in a single-mora word that sometimes occurs when the following case particle `を` is omitted in familiar speech.  This is described in *The Phonology of Japanese* (Labrune 2012) in section 2.7.5, 'Prosodic Lengthening'.

So as Yang Muye says, it means `手をふった`.

Comment: So it's not dialectal? Because I read somewhere that it was. But in my opinion it seems fairly common.

Comment: @YangMuye I don't think it's dialect. We pronounce it as [てぇふった]{LLHHL} in Kansai area, and I think it's pronounced like [てぇふった]{HHLLH} in Kanto area.