# What means 目えかける in this phrase?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

What means 目えかける in this phrase? Is a type of contraction?
What is the grammar behind this?

> 見所{みどころ}のある奴{やつ}に目{め}ぇかける

Comment: Is it a small ぇ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25600/1478