# What do the 「ああなる」and「気いします」mean?

Tags: colloquial-language, manga, kansai-ben, compensatory-lengthening

The sentence below is said by a Kansai-spoken character but I'm not sure if thetwo phrases are related to the dialect.

> みんなが**ああなる**気{き｝持｛も｝ち　ようわかるような**気｛き｝いします**感｛かん｝動｛どう｝してまんね　あいつら....

Comment: For ああ http://jisho.org/word/ああ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding 「ああ」, it is only the adverbial form of the 「あ」 from the famous 「**こそあど**」.  It means "***like that***", "***in that manner***", etc.  Thus, 「ああなる」 means "***to become that way***".

Note that this has ***nothing*** to do with Kansai speech; It is used all over the country.

The adverbial forms for こそあど are:

> こう、そう、**ああ** and どう

With 「ああ」 taking a different form from the other three, it might have tricked you somewhat.  We never say 「あう」 to mean 「ああ」.

Moving on to 「気{き}い」, which has ***everything*** to do with Kansai speech.　In Kansai, many one-syllable words are pronounced by elongating the single vowels.  So, 「気い」 simply means 「気」.  「気いします」 means 「気がします」 with the 「が」 dropped.

Thus, you will hear Kansai people say **in real life**:

・「目{め}え」 for 「目{め}」 ("eye")

・「歯{は}あ」 for 「歯」 ("teeth")

・「手{て}え」 for 「手」 ("hand")

Comment: 目え、歯あ、手え... ちゅうたらやっぱこれ思い出してまう → https://youtu.be/y9pyxscra1w?list=PL7iaP-xfMqH5sr1N5vkSQOXNtzwVd-XHb&t=174

Comment: While 気い may be unique to Kaisan-ben, 目え, 手え and such are [not really specific to Kansai-ben](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25600/5010). (Of course I understand the accent is different)

Answer (score 4):

The sentence should be partitioned differently.

みんながああなる気持ち　(が) ようわかるような気いします　感動してまんね　あいつら

ああ means あのように in standard Japanese,
while 気いします means 気がします in standard Japanese.

So the original sentence is translated to standard Japanese as follows:

みんながあのようになる気持ち(が)よくわかるような気がします　感動してますね　彼ら(は)

The last part is an anastrophe.
感動してまんね　あいつら = あいつらは感動してまんね = 彼らは感動してますね

Comment: 「ああ」って、標準語じゃないんですか？口語ではありますが、確か標準語ですよね…？

Comment: I love how in Japanese they rarely use pronouns, unless they really want to emphasize something about someone, and then they put the pronoun at the end, after a pause. :P あいつら

Comment: @Aeon Akechi, 「ああ」by itself might be a standard word, but it is a replacement for あのよう or a shortened version of ああいうこと... so maybe instead of "standard" Shenpai could have said "more formal" or something, but otherwise, he/she is accurate.