# Colloquial contraction “出しゃ[あ]”

Tags: translation, colloquial-language, contractions, conditionals, ellipsis

I encountered this sentence.

> なめんなよ。てめえみていな雑魚、おれが本気をだしゃあ…

I believe the context is quite obvious: The speaker feels stronger than his enemy, the listener. From how I understand it, I’d translate the sentence something like this:

> Don’t make fool of me! Against a small fry like you, I don’t even need to fight seriously.

Still, I can’t figure out, how the ending works to carry this meaning. My guesses so far are:

- The trailing あ is just an emotional prolongation – the verb form is just 出しゃ.
- The しゃ is some kind of contraction like e. g. なきゃ. But what of? Perhaps something like 出しては?

If these guesses are correct, there is probably still a part of the sentence missing as an ellipsis.

Thus, my question is: What are the missing or contracted parts and how do they form the meaning inferred from the context? Or maybe I got it completely wrong and the sentence means something else?

Comment: interesting, I did not know that "eba" contracts to "ya" .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

出しゃあ is a contraction of 出せば. Compare すれば → すりゃ, 書けば → 書きゃ, 死ねば → 死にゃ, ..., that is //eba// → //ʲa//.

The extra あ could be seen as a lengthening to compensate for the lost mora. (See also [手えふった - what is the "え” here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25600/1628))

Of course it means something like

> おれが本気をだせば...
>   If I were to get serious...

---

P.S. 出しては would usually contract to 出しちゃ

Comment: doh.... I messed up again?  What would the contracted form of 出したら look like? Or is there no such thing?

Comment: @ericfromabeno I don't think I know of a contraction for 出したら.

Answer (score 3):

> 「Verb in Dictionary Form - u + ya」

makes the ***colloquial hypothetical*** form of the verb, which in the formal form, would be:

> 「Verb in Dictionary Form - u + ***eba*** 」

Thus, 「出{だ}しゃ」 is the colloquial form of 「出せば」.

「おれが本気をだしゃあ」, therefore, means "***if I went all-out***" with the whole main clause describing the result left unsaid.  What is left unsaid would be something along the lines of "***You won't last a minute.***"